# How to run multiple asserts in django unittest?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest, django-testing

I am working on testing django application. I have following testcase.

```
from django.test import TestCase
class Mytest(TestCase):
    def test_01(self):
       self.client.login(username="testuser",password="test@12345")
       response=self.client.get(reverse('result'))

       self.assertEqual(response.context['data'],True)
       self.assertEqual(response.context['id'],'2')
```

Here when the first assert fails it mask the second one. How can i run both asserts even if one of them fails?